# Pandas filter dataframe based on condition for the first n rows

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe of shape [600 000, 19].  I want to filter the first 100 000 rows based on one condition, the next 300 000 based on another condition, and a 3rd condition for the last rows.  I was wondering how this can be done.

Currently, I split the data frame into 3 segments and apply their respective conditions.  Then, I re-concatenate the data frame.  Is there a better way?

Example:  Filter first 100 000 rows based on any value less than 5.  For second 300 000 rows, I dont want any values greater than 40, etc.

Comment: reset index into a column then you can incorporate the row sequence number into your condition

Comment: Try creating three masks using .iloc and then appply the three masks at once using 'or'  ( | ) to the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

```
import pandas as pd

sample = pd.DataFrame({'x' : pd.np.arange(100),
                       'colname': pd.np.arange(100)})
conditions = [('index < 5', 'colname < 3'), 
              ('index > 50', 'index < 100', 'colname < 55')]
sample.query('|'.join(map(lambda x: '&'.join(x), conditions)))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This definitely was able to accomplish the task without splitting and reconcat'ing.  I also learned a few other things about Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

On approach would be to use dataframe index slicing with `pd.concat` to build complete boolean series:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,60))

df[pd.concat([df.iloc[:10] > 10, df[11:40] < 30, df[41:] % 2 == 0])]
```

Where first 10 records filters less than 10, next 30 values filters greater than 30, and last values check for even numbers.

Then you can use dropna to remove all the NaN values

Output:

```
      0
0   44.0
1   47.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5   39.0
6    NaN
7   19.0
8   21.0
9   36.0
10   NaN
11   6.0
12  24.0
13  24.0
14  12.0
15   1.0
16   NaN
17   NaN
18  23.0
19   NaN
20  24.0
21  17.0
22   NaN
23  25.0
24  13.0
25   8.0
26   9.0
27  20.0
28  16.0
29   5.0
30  15.0
31   NaN
32   0.0
33  18.0
34   NaN
35  24.0
36   NaN
37  29.0
38  19.0
39  19.0
40   NaN
41   NaN
42  32.0
43   NaN
44   NaN
45  32.0
46   NaN
47  10.0
48   NaN
49   NaN
50   NaN
51  28.0
52  34.0
53   0.0
54   0.0
55  36.0
56   NaN
57  38.0
58  40.0
59   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is definitely a cleaner version of what I had originally, I then dropped the na's and reset the index and it works great.